# truffle migrate on ropsten shows Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: truffle, ropsten

I'm using ropsten test network for deploying my contracts. I'm using 

`"geth --fast --cache=1048 --testnet --unlock "0x35f5164d941de22942288808C1E6e406ec148336" --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545"`

for syncing. On my account I've 14eth as shown by etherscan.io and metamask but on "geth attach" after syncing it shows that the balance in 0. When i run "truffle migrate --network ropsten" its gives me error

"Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value"

This is my truffle -config.js

`module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 4500000
    },
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 4600000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000,
      from: "0x35f5164d941de22942288808C1E6e406ec148336"
    }
  }
};`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you specify the network during migration correctly as Ropsten??

Comment: yes i did mention the network as ropsten

Comment: @Try to reduce the gasPrice.

Comment: I've tried reducing gasPrice but still getting the same error

Comment: try the gas as gas:3000000

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: @NoManIlyas What does `eth.blockNumber` returns when executed from a geth console? If it returns 0 then your node isn't fully synchronized you will have to wait some time.

Comment: @Ismael I've deleted whole block chain and synced it again from scratch. on geth cosole ```eth.syncing``` returns false and ```eth.blockNumber``` returns 0. how much more time do I have to wait?

Comment: @Ismael now ```eth.blockNumber``` returns a block number. and when i try to deploy contracts it gets stuck for like 15-20 minutes then returns a error ```Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks```

Comment: You are better searching that error message, or asking a new question so it has visibility. I don't know exactly but I think it is related to low gas price, so your transaction is not mined within the expected range of 50 blocks.

Comment: after some time it started working. thanks for your help